# How do I configure proxy_pass on NGINX for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, nginx

I have a PostgreSQL server started at a remote machine on the port **15432**. I want to configure NGINX to make the database available remotely by host **db.domain.my** and port **5432**. The configuration I tried is:

```
server {
    listen 5432;
    server_name db.domain.my;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15432/;
    }
}
```

When I try to connect the database remotely with **psql** I get the error:

```
$ psql -h db.domain.my -U myuser
psql: received invalid response to SSL negotiation: H
```

I also tried to add **ssl** word after `listen 5432` without any success.

How do I configure NGINX correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe remove `http://` because it is a TCP connection (not a HTTP connection) and add `so_keepalive=on` to `listen 5432;` so the connection stays open.

Maybe you have to use `stream` instead of `http` block: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

Comment: The idea with `stream` sounds good. Thank you for the link. According to this topic I am unable to specify `server_name` for streams: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,263208,263217 . So the only thing I am allowed to do is port forwarding using `stream` in my NGINX configuration. I think this is the answer. Thank you.